# count=count++ make difference in linux and windows

Tags: c, linux, windows

I would like to know the reason why the two platforms behave inconsistently

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int count = 0;
    count = count++;
    printf("%d\n",count);  //linux count=0; windows count = 1; why? 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To quote from the duplicate, this is a textbook example of undefined behavior.

Comment: Note that both platforms produce acceptable answers.  The result is undefined by the standard (the result of undefined behaviour), so any result is okay.

Comment: Two questions: (1) Do you have an opinion on which of the two compilers is "correct"? (2) Would you *ever* write `count = count++` in a real program?  For me, at least, the answers are emphatically "no" and "no".

Comment: An insane person said to his two friends: "I do not not not not not not want to go to the party with you."  Friend #1 said, "Okay, so you do want to come!  Great!"  Friend #2 said, "Oh, well, sorry to hear you won't be coming."  Which friend interpreted the insane person's statement correctly?

Comment: When you compiled it on Linux (presumably using gcc or clang), did you notice the compiler warning saying something like "warning: operation on 'count' may be undefined"?  That should be a really big hint.  (Your Windows compiler may well have warned also, but I don't have one to test.)  Don't ignore compiler warnings!